# How to ignore characters in string

Tags: java

In the code below I am attempting to activate the if statement. In the if statement the xxxxx can be equal to any character of any length but the .txt at the end is required.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Example {
  public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    String save = keyboard.nextLine();

    if ("save xxxxx.txt".equals(save)) {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed!");
       }
   }
}
```

I should be able to input something such as:

- **"save hellothere.txt"** it should pass the if statement (because there is a save and .txt)
- **"save goodbyehelloletmegooo.txt"** should pass because there is a save and .txt

It should NOT pass in these situations:

- **"save hello"** it will not pass because there is no .txt
- **"hello.txt"** it will not pass because there is no save

All help appreciated thank you.

Comment: you should process "commands" and "file_name" in different operations

Comment: There is `String#startsWith` and `String#endsWith`. But you should really split into words and process them separately.

Answer (score 2):

Try some RegEx, like this:

```
if (save.matches("save .+\\.txt")) {
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a combination of `String::contains` and `String::endsWith` will solve this.

```
if (save.contains("something") && save.endsWith("something")){
    //do something 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    String save = keyboard.nextLine();
    String s = "save "+save.replace("save", "").replace(".txt", "").trim()+".txt";

    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(save);

    if (s.equals(save))
    {
        System.out.println("Success!");
    }
    else 
    {
        System.out.println("Failed!");
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use a `Regex` with some basics constraints like

```
token.matches("save\\.[A-Z]*[0-9]*[_]*[-]*\\.txt"))
```

to constraint this further.

Comment: When OP would like to use a regex, then he/she should use one which would actually make sense. Do you understand what the regex in your example means and how Strings look like it accepts?

Comment: I am trying to illustrate a general example, the OP can choose between characters, number or some special characters as per the requirement, I have allowed only alphabets, numbers,underscores and hyphens, the op can build from here.

Comment: Nonsense. Your regex allows "save" followed by a whitespace, followed by any character (but only one), then there ___must___ be an uppercase letter, then there ___must___ be a number and then there ___must___ be an underscore and then there ___must___ be at least one hyphen, but it allows more than one. OP never said something about an order of these characters, that they are mandatory and that only one of each should be allowed. That's why I asked: do you understand what the regex in your example means? I guess you don't.